# dynamic radio button creation using handlebars in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

For a game I am creating,I have an array of objects like this (please ignore the silly effects/results) :

```
issues = [
{
    uid: 1,
    question: "Should Marijuana be legalized?",
    options: [
        {
            statment: "Yes Please, It is better than alcohol",
            result: "Smokes fill up the skies",
            effect: {
                goldBonus: 0.2,
                Spirituality: 1,
                offenseBonus: -0.5,
                counterIntelBonus: -0.2
            }
        },  
        {
            statment: "No it is against the civilized society",
            result: "Jails are full of blazed teens",
            effect: {
                goldBonus: -0.2,
                Spirituality: -1,
                counterIntelBonus: +2
            }
        }   
    ] 
},
{
    uid: 2,
    question: "Should children be banned from playing in the streets?",
    options: [
        {
            statment: "Yes, they are pests",
            result: "clean efficient traffic free roads",
            effect: {
                goldBonus: 1,
                ironBonus: 1,
                populationBonus: -0.2,
                HDI: -0.5
            }
        },  
        {
            statment: "No, children should be free to play wherever they want",
            result: "Roads are full of kids running around playing",
            effect: {
                goldBonus: -0.2,
                HDI: 2
            }   
        },
        {
            statment: "Drivers get paid to kidnap kids on roads and deliver to army",
            result: "No kids are found outside their house in the fear of being snatched up by the govt.", 
            effect: {
                goldBonus: 0.5,
                populationBonus: -2,
                offenseBonus: 3,
                defenseBonus: 3,
                HDI: -5
            }   
        }
    ]       
},
]
```

Based on this array, I am trying to create a radio-button form for every issue in the issues array. The helper function is as follows:

```
Template.HomePrivateIssues.helpers ({

  issues: function () {
    return issues;
  }

});
```

And the template is:

```
<template name = "HomePrivateIssues">
    <div class = "issue">
        {{#each issues}}
            <form>
                <div class = "question">{{question}}</div>
                {{#each options}}
                    <input type = "radio" name = "test" value = "{{this.statement}}" > {{this.statment}} <br>
                {{/each}}
                <input type = "submit">
            </form>
        {{/each}}   
    </div>
</template>
```

I am running into problems while defining name and value for the forms 
simple `name = {{this.uid}}` or `name = "{{this.uid}}"` does not seem to work.

if I keep the name or value constant (e.g.: name = "test" value = "obama"), I can simply use ..

```
Template.HomePrivateIssues.events({
  'submit': function(event, template) {
    var element = template.find('input:radio[name=test]:checked');
    console.log($(element).val());
  }
});
```

I get `obama` in my console. 
I am at a loss on how to generate the value and name dynamically and pass it to event when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

OK first lets change the html.

```
<div class = "issue">
    {{#each issues}}
            <div class = "question">{{question}}</div>
            {{#each options}}
            <form>
                <input type="radio" name="test" value="{{this.statment}}">{{this.statment}}
            {{/each}}
            <button id="lol"> Click </button> <!-- i preffer to work with button change to input if you want -->
        </form>
    {{/each}}   
</div>
```

Here we add a Form inside the `{{#each options}}`

Now we need to change a little bit the `event` function

```
  Template.HomePrivateIssues.events({
  'click #lol': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = $(":radio[name=test]:checked").val();
    console.log(value)
  }
});
```

here we just add the `event.preventDefault();` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp), for more information about `preventDefault();`.

Try it, it should work

Comment: I forgot to add event.preventDefault();  I did use it. But paint me an idiot ... I spelled "statement" wrong  in the data.  No wonder this.statement was not working.  Let me fix this now, and see how it works.

Comment: Also, can you explain why you are using two form tags? thank you for the quick reply

Comment: Well yep i just copy/paste the code, and after refreshing the page, i make "inspect element", and i see that the radio buttons dosnt have any values so i erase the html code and made a new one, and make my own js events, i didn't see too the "statement" word haha i think we are 2 idiots here haha